# Discovering new elements in zero gravity and in orbit?

Tags: gravity, elements

Can we discover new elements in zero gravity of space and on other worlds with less gravity? To perhaps discover some of these elements, that we're having trouble producing here on earth? Would less gravity aid or even effect.. in the pursuit of discovery of new elements?

Comment: no, it will not. Gravity's influence on nuclear reaction on earth is practically nil.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the deal:

Atoms of a particular element are comprised of protons, neutrons, and electrons.  The number of neutrons can vary among atoms of the same element (we call these different isotopes), and the number of electrons can also be different (we call these different ions).  It is the number of protons, sometimes denotes with the symbol $Z$, that determines the element.  For example, all hydrogen atoms in the entire cosmos of an atomic number of 1 ($Z=1$).  For all carbon atoms, $Z=6$, for all oxygen atoms, $Z=8$, and so on for different elements.

However, as the atomic number of an atom gets larger and larger and larger, the atom becomes more unstable.  Uranium, ($Z=92$) is well-known as being a radioactive element; in fact every single isotope of Uranium is unstable, and will eventually decay into atoms with smaller nuclei.  And Uranium is special because in terms of atomic number, it's the last element that is naturally occurring.  For all element with $Z>92$, they are SO unstable that they can only be created in labs, by temporarily smashing together two smaller atoms.  Generally, these trans-Uranium elements, as they're called, only last for a smaller time being.

The forces that hold these atoms together, and thus determine the various nuclei of atoms form depend only on short range forces that, as far as we can tell, work the same no matter where in the universe we are (not withstanding things like black-holes, where our current understanding of the laws of physics cannot completely describe yet).  So whether you're here, or on Jupiter, or in the Andromeda galaxy, the general array of elements you see will be the same.

Comment: Sums it up very nicely...

Comment: @dmckee I am sorry , I just deleted my "answer", I do take your point, I assumed the OP meant elements in commercial amounts.